# How to properly use importScript() and instantiate a new class based on that script?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Ive looked far and wide but I cant find a good example of how importScript() works for a web worker. Getting the web worker to run is fine but attempting to get it to create a new latLng object causes the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: latLng is not defined "

Web Worker

```
importScripts("latLngReplace.js")

this.onmessage = (records)->

     for record, i in JSON.parse(records.data) when record.shape? # loop through zip codes
          console.log record.City+" at "+ i
          for polygon in record.shape # loop through array of polygons (usually a zip code is one polygon)
               zip_coords = [] 
               for point in polygon.split(', ') # loop through all coords in a zip area
                    point_array = point.split(' ')

                    if point_array[1].split('.')[1]
                         lat=point_array[1].split('.')[1].length
                    else
                         lat=0
                    if point_array[0].split('.')[1]
                         lon=point_array[0].split('.')[1].length
                    else
                         lon=0
                    zip_coords.push new latLng(
                         parseFloat(point_array[1]).toFixed( lat ),
                         parseFloat(point_array[0]).toFixed( lon )
                    )


               postMessage(zip_coords)
```

latLngReplace.js

```
class latLng
     lat:null
     lng:null
     constructor:(latitude, longitude)->
          console.log "creating a lat long object"
          @lat=latitude
          @lng=longitude          

     lat:=>
          return @lat   
     lng:=>
          return @lng
     toString:=>
          return "lat:"+@lat+", lng"+@lng
     equals:(latlng)=>
          if latlng.lat() == @lat and latlng.lng() ==@lng
              return true
          else 
              return false
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

After hemming and hawing a great deal, the only solution I found was to remove the importScripts and append the contents of latLngReplace.js (technically it was a coffee file that was posted even though it was a JS file of equivalence used in actuality) to the bottom of the web worker.

Hardly the optimal solution when you want to keep code separate but it was the only solution I could come up with.

If anyone in the future finds a means to use importScripts properly and in a similar manner, feel free to add the knowledge here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're defining a private class in `latLngReplace`, so it's not available when you import the script. Try prefixing the class name with `@`:

```
class @latLng
```

That should make your class public.